# Join 2 resultant tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries to get data from my database.

```
SET @row_num0 = 0;
SELECT @row_num0 := @row_num0 + 1 AS RIdx1,
       U.name
FROM users U


SET @row_num1= 0;
SELECT @row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1 AS RIdx2,
       C.color
FROM colors C
```

I want to join the result from 1st Query `RIdx1` to 2nd Query `RIdx2`.

Explanation.... I want to get a unique color from `color table` for each users from `user table` 

I had tired of using `nested SELECT` and I can't use `SET @` under SELECT .

Is there anyway I can use to get color for each user?

Edited::::

The nested SELECT Query....

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SET @row_num0 = 0;
    SELECT @row_num0 := @row_num0 + 1 AS RIdx1,
           U.name
    FROM users U
) DATA0
LEFT JOIN
(
    SET @row_num1= 0;
    SELECT @row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1 AS RIdx2,
           C.color
    FROM colors C
) DATA1
ON DATA0.RIdx1 = DATA1.RIdx2
```

SQL Error occurs. I cannot join these two select query. Please help....

Comment: Are there more colors than there are users?

Comment: nope.... Just used Limit to get exact amount of colors for users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following :

```
SELECT @row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1 AS RIdx2
     , C.color
  FROM colors C
  CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @row_num1:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
  BY color;
```

Comment: How do I join with user table?

Comment: Can u please explain me a bit more?

Comment: Yeahh.....your Query select the color from the color table That I got earlier. I want to join the result from color table to the results from users table.

Comment: You have all the information you need to figure this out.

Comment: `SELECT 
 DATA0.color,
 DATA1.name1
FROM (
 SELECT @row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1 AS RIdx1
      , C.color
 FROM default_color C
) DATA0
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT @row_num2 := @row_num2 + 1 AS RIdx2,
  U.name1
 FROM users U
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num2 := 0) A
) DATA1
ON DATA0.RIdx1 = DATA1.RIdx2`
That worked.

Comment: Nearly, but not quite.